# How to load a video instead of a 3d object file in VRToolKit?

Tags: iphone, ios5, augmented-reality

I am working on some augmented reality apps development on iPhone iOS 5, I am using `VRToolKit` Plus, the demo project only shows some `3D Objects` on the marker when it is detected. But I want to show a small video clip on the place of 3D Object. How can I do this ?

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: No, i haven't got any easy solution....